# How to stop Webkit native scroll momentum after disabling and re-enabling scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, webkit

I have a tricky problem with Webkit browsers and some custom scrolling behaviour.

On my page, I am detecting scroll, and when it happens, disable the scroll by making the `body` have `overflow:hidden` and then do some custom animation logic for the scroll position.

The problem on Webkit browsers (Mac OS) is when I re-enable scroll the native scroll seems to still be easing out, thus moving the page some more in the direction of the initial scroll event, which is undesirable in this case.

Is there a way to disable/reset native scroll or native scroll momentum?

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/kontur/pen/abWjYwM?editors=0010) illustrating the problem. *HOWEVER* you need to download it as zip and run locally — whatever codepen is doing to the preview container prevents the "native" scroll that is causing the issue. When viewing locally and scrolling "down" what you should see in:

- Firefox (the desired behaviour): For 25 frames after the scroll, the scroll position should not move, the page background should be beige. Only when scrolling **again** should the page animate again
- Webkit: After 25 frames after the scroll, you'll see the page flicker white when the animation timeout finishes, and **without** scrolling anew the "old" native scroll easing seems to still be "ramping down", which triggers the scroll event, and immediately paints the page background beige again. I'd like to avoid this "old native scroll" triggering after I reenable the scrolling.

Comment: Can you please add some minimum code which shows the problem because I'm not completely clear how your animation may be affecting the scrolling behavior.

Comment: @AHaworth See the codepen (download locally to reproduce) — the animation does not matter one bit; in fact, in the example the animation code is `// do nothing` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use a different element than `body` as scroll wrapper. Apparently this behaviour of "resuming" momentum scrolling when re-formatting the body to be scrollable (have overflow) is hard-coded, whereas other scrollable elements do not exhibit this unpredictable side-effect.